# Is there an improved IDE for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I am looking for a modern, highly usable, single package IDE/wrapper for Eclipse (if such things exist). Something that would provide a wrapper to Eclipse and add some style, a nicer interface, better code highlighting, etc. Any suggestions?

Edit:
-Java
-Looking for a nicer "prettier" IDE with more visual features and code completions, etc. 
-Should be able to install it on a live Eclipse install

Comment: What language, specifically what is wrong with Eclipse?

Comment: Java. And actually I am going to reword this a bit, see question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse is one of the best IDEs in terms of code completion and refactoring features.  If your concerns are mainly style, you can customize syntax coloring using the Preferences > Java > Editor > Syntax Coloring menu.  Or check out [color themes here](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/).

If you want a different skin for Eclipse you could try [here](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/skins/index.html).  There are also code visualization plugins and style warnings, but you need to be specific about what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Aptana is pretty good, [www.aptana.com](http://www.aptana.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's going to give you everything you're asking for, but there is [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts).